# jquery ui datepicker not working in my rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datepicker

Am using jquery ui datepicker for select date in my rails app. When I give javascript and stylesheet link reference directly in view page, datepicker was working. When i give in application.html.erb file its not working..

My application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

My application.css

```
*= require jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css
*= require mystyle.css
```

My application.html.erb

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Application</title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application'  %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "highcharts", "chartkick" %>  
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

View:

```
 Entrydate<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Checkout the developers console first if there is any error. Then comeback with the screenshots if any errors is being displayed!

Comment: no error in console.@Tomanow

Comment: Try load the CSS files before javascript files

Comment: How to load CSS before javascript..? @rejnev

Comment: I don't know what technology your web application is using, but usually when you require some resources, you should write the **require** commands for loading CSS files before requiring javascripts

Comment: i given require commands.. But its not working. @rejnev

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing it with Bootstrap datepicker. Keep to jQuery UI DatePicker by following the gem docu at https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails